# Transition to innodb_file_per_table for 30+ databases

Tags: mysql, mariadb-5.5

Currently I have a MySQL Server with `innodb_file_per_table = 0`

Based on a number of factors, it seems to make sense for me to change that to `innodb_file_per_table = 1`

I understand that to make this all work I need to

1. Use mysqldump to export all databases into individual files
2. Shutdown mysql
3. Change the `innodb_file_per_table` setting
4. Restart mysql
5. Import each database

Question is, can I do the following

**Day #1**

1. Shutdown mysql
2. Change the `innodb_file_per_table` setting
3. Restart mysql
4. Export some databases
5. Import those databases back into mysql

**Day #2**

1. Export some databases
2. Import those databases back into mysql

Until I've exported an re-imported all of the databases?

I'm assuming that during the transition some databases will continue to use the ibdata1 file while the exported and re-imported database will use their own datastores.  Will having a mix of datastores cause issues or am I OK doing a phased transition?

Comment: Are the factors you mentioned actually noticeable?

Comment: Neither approach will shrink `ibdata1`.  What is your goal behind doing the change?  There are other possible goals.  And there are other techniques.

Comment: @RickJames Maybe I should first be asking if I shoul dbe doing this.  Do you know of a good resource online that would help me understand when innodb_file_per_table is the right way to go and when it's not?  I'm concerned about the size of my ibdata1 file (35GB), the risk of corruption and backup/restore options for individual databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have a reference for when to set `innodb_file_per_table` in different ways.  Here are some tips:

- Note:  The value of `innodb_file_per_table` applies *only* to *subsequent* `CREATE TABLEs` or table rebuilding.
- [Perhaps the main reason for turning it ON:]  When you have a "big" table that might be `ALTERed`, or you might do a lot of deleting, etc, it is somewhat advisable to build the table with file_per_table ON.  This allows the operation to replace the .ibd file containing just that one table.
- Hence, if the table is being shrunk *significantly* by the operation, the extra space that is freed up is returned to the OS.  That is, the only easy way to return free space to the OS is to have file_per_table on and do some operation that rebuilds the table.
- file_per_table = OFF is *slightly* better for "small" tables that will stay small.  This because of sharing a single file descriptor (for `ibdata1`) for many tables.
- To change file_per_table for a table requires (1) setting the flag and (2) rebuilding the table (eg, simply `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB;`; it may need `FORCE`).  After that, consider changing the setting back.
- When running tight on disk space, it might help to play games by moving selected tables between `ibdata1` (which may have a lot of free space) and separate .ibd files.
- Moving a file *out of* ibdata1 leaves a bunch of free space behind.  This space may eventually get used by `INSERTs` and other operations on the tables in ibdata1.
- Dumping and integrity are not affected by ibdata1 vs .ibd.
- Most servers should not worry about the setting.
- [A related topic:]  `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is essentially never necessary for InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly wouldn't bother unless you have a specific problem you are solving.

Its possible to do simpler with:

1. Shutdown
2. change setting innodb_file_per_table = 1
3. start
4. `ALTER TABLE xxx FORCE` for each table

Comment: Caveat:  `ibdata1` will not shrink when using `ALTER`.